# SQL Server : stored procedure data issue

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have an explanation as to why data from a stored procedure seems to be corrupt when the procedure is scheduled to run or is executed from VBA in an Access database?

The problem I am having is that a CTE query that builds a bill of material does not want to run when the data comes from a stored procedure that is executed in the previously mention ways. I can delete the data and execute the stored procedure from Management Studio and the CTE query works fine.

The stored procedure is pretty basic it just insert a `BOM` table and adds a date so I can see how the BOM changes from day to day. The `BOM` table was coming from a view I created from a linked server but I changed the stored procedure to just use the linked server information but it still causes problems.

```
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO daily_bom 
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Getdate(), 101)   AS BOM_Date, 
           plantnumber, 
           bomnumber, 
           parentassembly, 
           bomusage, 
           CONVERT(INT, bomalternativenumber) BOMAleternativeNumber, 
           bomalternativetext, 
           componentmaterial, 
           CONVERT(FLOAT, sequencelinenumber) SequenceLineNumber, 
           itemcategory, 
           CONVERT(REAL, componentquantity)   ComponentQuantity, 
           fixedquantity, 
           componentunitofmeasure, 
           assemblyindicator, 
           phantomindicator, 
           costingrelevant, 
           engineeringrelevant, 
           productionrelevant, 
           ecnnumber, 
           ecneffectivedate, 
           ecnnumberto, 
           ecneffectiveenddate, 
           xrefnumber, 
           referencedesignator, 
           itemid, 
           procurementtype, 
           documentnumber, 
           dtsdate, 
           dateoflastchange, 
           senttoproductionsuitedatetime, 
           lastidocprocessed, 
           inserttoproductionsuite, 
           lastidocserial 
    FROM   sap_bill_of_material 
END
```

I'll try to spell this issue out a little better for some of you, so just ignore the CTE part of it. If I schedule the stored procedure to run over night and run a query on that data it takes an unusual amount of time to run. If I delete that data and execute the stored procedure or manually kick off the scheduled job in SQL Server Agent in SSMS and query the data it runs fine.

So every morning when I come in and try to query the data is runs really slow like a few minutes vs. a few seconds (causes the CTE to still be running over 5 mins vs. 23 secs). If I delete the data and rerun the stored procedure it seems to work fine (I have checked and I do delete the same amount of lines that I am inserting when I run the stored procedure again). Any idea as to what would cause this i.e. pc not being awake, something running on the server at the time the stored procedure is run.

Edit Added 1/11/16

Still nothing on this one. I figured someone would have seen this issue before. The only other thing I have tried to do to get the CTE query to run in a decent amount of time is dumping the table it queries into another temp table and querying off of that. This method works fine. Still no idea why it would take so long (haven't actually let it finish since it's gone up to 10 minutes) when querying the actual table the data comes from.

Comment: What are the issues?

Comment: Not sure whats your problem which you forgot to explain, But two things here 1. Always mention the column list when you are doing `INSERT`. 2. Store the dates as `date` type instead of `varchar`

Comment: LOL, Not sure how to explain it any better. My CTE query is fine. My stored procedure is fine. The data looks exactly the same when I schedule the stored procedure as it does when I execute it from ssms. The problem is that the cte query doesn't or possibly takes hours to finish when the data comes from the stored procedure when it was scheduled to run vs. me just running the stored procedure from ssms then execute the cte query.

Comment: See if the query plan is different between the fast and slow executions.

Comment: A CTE is specified with `; WITH <common_table_expression>`. There is no CTE in the query you posted. If you are having problem with a query that *does* have a CTE, could you please include that in your question? In any case, often a CTE is not materialized which can result in a very unoptimized execution plan. Your workaround by materializing in a temp table is usually the way to go (there exists a trick to get a CTE materialized using `TOP  2147483647 ... ORDER BY ...`, but it's more of a hack). Also include the execution plan in your question.

Comment: Thanks TT but read the question again. The issue seems to be the data that is inserted into a table from a stored procedure that is scheduled to run overnight. The CTE is the least of my worries. It works just fine.